# POSTMAN works, but android okhttp request responds different value

Tags: android, retrofit2

So, I try to receive an answer from server.
I tried this first at postman using these settings and it WORKS!

[image]

I use `RequestBody` to form request in code:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "grant_type=idk&password=" + password + "&username=" + username);
```

Service interface:

```
@POST("v1/token")
Call<X> auth(@Body RequestBody body);
```

And this will lead to 400 error. Why and how to fix this?

Comment: formUrlEncoded annotation need to be there

Comment: You should post more code... We can't understand anything. Post models, call method... try to debug to see the full URL...

Comment: @AkashDubey depends the server configs, but... yeah, 
that may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your values in URL only even though you have written POST method.

You should change as below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v1/token")
Call<X> auth(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

and you can call as below:

```
Call<X> call = retrofitInterface.auth(username, password);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Anotation **@UrlEncoded** in **Service interface** and Call Request body this way:-

RequestBody body = RequestBody.Companion.create(json, JSON)
Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();